# Ошибка в discord.py при вызове modal menu

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Всем доброго времени суток, у меня возникла необходимость создать модальное меню ввода в дискорде, используя библиотеку discord.py
При запуске кода у меня выскакивает ошибка:

```
    class SignUp(discord.ui.Modal, title = 'Регистрация'):
TypeError: SignUp.__init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments
```

Вот код:

```py
class SignUp(discord.ui.Modal, title = 'Регистрация'):
    NickName = discord.ui.InputText(
        style = discord.InputTextStyle.short,
        label = 'Ваш ник в игре (Отображаемое в игре)',
        required = True,
        max_length = 32,
        min_length = 3,
        placeholder = 'Введите своё отображаемое имя'
    )
        
    Password = discord.ui.InputText(
        style = discord.InputTextStyle.short,
        label = 'Введите пароль',
        required = True,
        max_length = 32,
        min_length = 8,
        placeholder = 'Введите пароль'
    )
        
    Reason = discord.ui.InputText(
        style = discord.InputTextStyle.long,
        label = 'Причина',
        required = False,
        max_length = 500,
        placeholder = 'Расскажите, как вы узнали о существовании данного бота? (не обязательно)'
    )
    async def on_error(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, error):
         ...
    async def on_sumbit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, error):
         ...
```

Здесь я пытался вызвать модальное меню:

```
async def signup(interaction):
    signup = SignUp()
    await interaction.response.send_modal(signup)
```

Я буду очень рад вашей помощи!

Comment: Я думаю, что `title = 'Регистрация'` нужно указать в конструкторе класса (`__init__`), а не закидывать в список родителей класса